# FirePHP does not show extras when used with Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug

Tags: php, zend-framework, firebug, firephp, zend-log

I've been developing with Zend Framework for ages (since 0.9) and this problem is nagging at my nerves ever since.

I want to output messages on the FireBug Console with the help of FirePHP and from a Zend Framework 1.11 Application. I've configured Firebug with the default application.ini-file:

```
resources.log.firebug.writerName = "Firebug"
resources.log.firebug.filterName = "Priority"
resources.log.firebug.filterParams.priority = 7
```

I can now see messages in FireBug, e.g. in the IndexController, by calling an invalid action or by explicitly throwing Exceptions like

```
throw new Exception("This is my error message", E_USER_ERROR);
```

This results in the default ErrorController handling the Exception and showing a stack trace and request parameters:

[image: Request Parameters]

The default ErrorController will also log all messages automatically to FireBug:

[image: Firebug Success]

However, as you can see, the extra-information like the stack trace or the request parameters are not shown, although FireBug is quite able to do so, as may be seen in this Screenshot of FireBug when visiting the mainpage:

[image: Detailed Firebug window]

As the documentation states, Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug will ignore all [writerParams](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.factory.html#zend.log.factory.writer-options.firebug), with which a defaultPriorityStyle may be set to TRACE or something similar.

Now for my question: Is there any way to configure Zend Framework to also send over the extra data (as shown in the last picture) without having to use [firePHPcore](http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Use.htm), but with the tools coming with Zend Framework itself?

Best Regards and Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot achieve what you're saying with the default error controller generated from `zf create project` because the lines involved are these

```
// Log exception, if logger available
if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
    $log->log($this->view->message, $priority, $errors->exception);
    $log->log('Request Parameters', $priority, $errors->request->getParams());
}
```

i.e. the default error controller only log the message, the priority and the exception and the firebug writer format them in the way you shown.

To achieve what you're saying you should hack the `Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug` class to display the stacktrace using the firebug console or alternatively you can play with a custom formatter class added to your logger.

I did something similar by creating a mail logger which displays formatted exception stacktrace in a mail message and use when in production to obtain a formatted log of the exception sent by email. You can find it [here on Github](https://github.com/fabn/zle/tree/develop/library/Zle/Log) and [here](http://www.codewithstyle.eu/2011/01/26/zend-framework-exception-notifier/) you can find its usage.

Moreover you can see an example on how to use the firebug console using the ZF classes in the [`Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Profiler/Firebug.php) class.

So to answer your question, no you can't do that without writing some custom class and it as writer or formatter to the log object nor you can do that by just using the `application.ini` file.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts - I actually can edit the Error-Controller and could add the extra-information of the log to the first parameter - but then I won't get the wanted functionality of expanding or collapsing entries. I played around with the Formatter as well and I may be able to get the result I want by enhancing the Logger-class. However, I feel that the Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug should use the possibility of FirePHP/FireBug be default.